# the package react does not satisfy its siblings

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, npm

Continuously receiving this error when attempting to deploy to Galaxy or run any meteor command for that matter. I've tried removing the npm-container folder. Removing and re-adding meteorhacks:npm. No bueno :(

```
   While building package npm-container:
   error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap: Command failed: npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No description
   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No repository field.
   npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-npm-container@0.0.0 No README data
   npm WARN engine escodegen@1.8.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
   npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer newforms@0.13.2 wants react@>=0.14.0
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer newforms-bootstrap@2.0.0 wants react@>=0.13.0
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap-modal@2.0.0 wants react@^0.14.0
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@0.14.6 wants react@^0.14.6
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix this or still encountering issues?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you have several packages relying on different versions of React as a [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/). When a package has a peer dependency defined, it means that they will not install that package itself, but will expect that you already have it installed as a main dependency.

Going off of [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver), it actually looks like all of those peer dependencies should be compatible so what likely has happened is that you have an older version of React installed that is compatible with your main dependencies but lower than the peer dependencies. I would check to make sure your main React dependency is at least `^0.14.6`, wipe away `node_modules`, and then run another `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update last npm

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```